# How do I create a Rubix Cube in python using Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have been trying to make a Rubix Cube in python using Matplotlib. I've struggled to get each face of the cube to have its own colour? How do I do this in Matplotlib?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import numpy as np

axes = [3, 3, 3]
data = np.ones(axes)

alpha = 0.9
colours = np.empty(axes + [4])

colours[0] = [1, 0, 0, alpha] # red
colours[1] = [0, 0, 1, alpha] # blue
colours[2] = [1, 1, 0, alpha] # yellow

figure = plt.figure()
ax = figure.add_subplot(111, projection = '3d')

ax.voxels(data, facecolors = colours, edgecolors = 'grey')

plt.show()
```

Comment: How many faces does a cube have?

Comment: If you want to change the individual colors, you can do so by arranging the colors to match the structure in three dimensions, but is this what you intend? `import random;colours=np.array(random.choices(['red','blue','yellow','orange','white','green'], k=3**3)).reshape(axes)`

Comment: @r-beginners this worked great! However each individual cube of block colour. For example a corner piece is yellow on all three visible faces. On a rubix cube a corner piece has 3 different colours on each visible face. Is there a way to change this so that on each individual cube there are corresponding colours? Thanks

Comment: If there are rules on how to display them, then according to those rules I should just create a list of colors. I am not familiar with those rules, so I used random numbers to create the list.